# How to refresh application deployed in Linux machine

Tags: linux, compilation, assets

I have deployed `angular` application in Sandbox Linux machine. When replacing data in `assets` folder those changes are not reflecting in website. Though I am using `sudo service restart httpd` command.

I am using `Putty` command prompt and connecting to server via ssh

How can I reflect the changes or recompile code/application using commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to depend on how your build/deploy toolchain for angular works.

Basically, httpd reads the files on the filesystem. When you update the files, you don't need to restart the httpd service. It will serve up whatever is there.

However, angular is another story.  You're probably on the right path that you probably need to recompile your angular application, but with what you've provided I don't think we can answer that for you, other than to say:

Here are the docs about deploying angular apps: https://angular.io/guide/deployment